# Atmega16 USART initialization

Tags: usart, atmega16

I can't for the life of me find why this code is not working to send a byte to my computer terminal window. It receives and works fine when I omit that line though.  Receiving and sending also work seperately.  Please note that this is over rs485 so I must disable TXEN if I want anything received to make it through the line driver ic.

```
#define F_CPU 7800000UL  // 7.8 MHz
#include <avr/io.h>
//#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <math.h>
#define USART_BAUDRATE 57600  
#define BAUD_PRESCALE (((F_CPU / (USART_BAUDRATE * 16UL))) - 1)

volatile unsigned int value = 0;
volatile int recievearray[4] = {0,0,0,0};
volatile int x=0;  

void USART_Init(void)
{
   DDRD = 0x7E; //you have to assign TXEN as output for some reason
   //PORTD = 0xFF;
   UCSRB = 0;
   //Put the upper part of the baud number here (bits 8 to 11)
   UBRRH = (unsigned char) (BAUD_PRESCALE >> 8);

   //Put the remaining part of the baud number here
   UBRRL = (unsigned char) BAUD_PRESCALE;
   //PORTD = 2;
   // ASYNCRONOUS
   UCSRC = (0 << UMSEL);

   //Enable the receiver and transmitter
   UCSRB = (1 << RXEN) | (1 << TXEN) | (0 << UCSZ2) | (1<<RXCIE);

   //Set 1 stop bits and data bit length is 8-bit
   UCSRC = (1 << URSEL) | (0 << USBS) | (3 << UCSZ0);
   //no parity
   UCSRC |= (0 << UPM1);
   UCSRC |= (0 << UPM0);
 }


void USART_SendByte(uint8_t u8Data)
{  
  UCSRB = (1 << TXEN) | (1<<TXCIE); 

  // Wait until last byte has been transmitted
  while((UCSRA &(1<<UDRE))==0);
  UDR = u8Data;
  UCSRB = (0 << TXEN) | (0<<TXCIE);
}

void Led_init(void){
     DDRC = 0xFF;       
}

ISR(USART_RXC_vect)
{   
    //PORTC = 0xFF;
    while((UCSRA &(1<<RXC)) == 0);
    value = UDR;
if (x < 4)
{
    recievearray[x++] = value;
}
else
{
    x = 0;
    recievearray[x++] = value;
    PORTC = 0x00;
}
}


int main(void)
{
   USART_Init();
   sei();         
   Led_init();    
   //PORTC = 0xFF;
   for(;;)
   {        
        if (recievearray[0] + recievearray[1] + recievearray[2] +       recievearray[3] > 100)
        {
            PORTC = 0xFF;
            USART_SendByte(value);
        }

        //_delay_ms(1000);              
   }
}
```